# What is the pronunciation of 行 in the meaning 'saṃskāra'?

Tags: pronunciation, middle-chinese, buddhism

One of the meanings of 行 is *saṃskāra*, 'formations', one of the five Buddhist skandhas. What is the pronunciation of 行 in this meaning?

The question is motivated by Kroll's *Student's Dictionary of Classical and Medieval Chinese* specifically giving the reading to be **haengH** > *xìng*, putting it separately from the usual **haeng** > *xíng*.

But what is the source of that? All general dictionaries I could consult, as dense as the Hanyu Da Zidian, do not contain the *saṃskāra* meaning, so they cannot be used to check it. On the other hand, all specifically Buddhist sources I found agree with the usual *xíng*:

- The *Digital Dictionary of Buddhism* (http://www.buddhism-dict.net) knows only *xíng* for all meanings of 行;
- The venerable *Glossary of Kumārajīva's Translation Of The Lotus Sutra* by Karashima Seishi, who I think can be fully trusted as an expert, has only *xíng* specifically for *saṃskāra* meaning;
- Of lesser value, but still notable, is the fact that the 一切經音義 does not to have a pronunciation of 行 given anywhere, thus expecting the readers to use the most ordinary reading;
- The pinyin spellings of the Heart Sutra that I could find have *xíng* in the phrase 受想行識亦復如是 which definitely refers to the *saṃskāras*.

Is there a difference in reading, after all?

Comment: The 行 of 諸行無常 seems to be for this meaning. How is this four-character sequence pronounced in Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

I would say 行 xíng = 生死

行: 流通，传递: circulate, circle

> 2 / 生死或生死陰 ‘生死’， literally meaning birth and death, or samsara in the
> sense of painful worldly existence, was a general term to render the
> word samskara in the early Buddhist literature before Kumarajiva. It
> occurs almost as frequently as‘行’， however it is used most often in a
> collective numeration of five aggregates: 色、痛痒、思想、生死、識(註16). When used
> individually, it may appear accompanied by ‘陰’， ‘生死陰’ understood as
> 'samskaraskandha' [ T.15, 164c, etc. ] and differentiated from samsara
> as such.
>
> However this differentiation is usually completely obliterated in the
> early period. It is also frequently used together with‘行’， in the
> sense of involvement in worldly existence as opposed to
> liberation(註17), or blind wandering in Samsara as opposed to
> truth(註18). Since the samskaras are said to arise in virtue of three
> factors: karma, desire and ignorance [T.2, 88b] ,the translation of
> samskara by samsara is philosophically impeccable.
>
> It clarifies its function as the architect of other four skandhas, but
> it fails to translate many particular usages of samskara in Pali, such
> as preparations of. body, speech and mind (kaya, vaci, manosankhara),
> or preperation of life, or of age [ jivitasankhara, ayusankhara ]
> etc., where always other words had to be used. 身、口、意行作…T. 15, 175b].
>
> As the translation of samskara as‘行’ is used in juxtaposition with the
> description of Nirvana as unmoved (acala) , or constant [[[dhuva]]),
> so its translation as ‘生死’, brings to light its unborn [[[ajata]]) and
> deathless acuta, amara nature.
>
> This contrast is often used by the commentators as for example Xi Chao
> for whom samskara as‘生死’, seems to signify the process of arising and
> passing of [a defiled] mind. (註19) The commentator of 'Shi er yin jing
> [ dvadasanidanasutra ] identifies samskara 生 死 with the root
> defilement of anger or dislike, lust with ignorance and consciousness
> with not knowing or essential unclarity(註20).
>
> These three (consciousness, samskara and ignorance) are here
> undistinguishable, as in many other places in the early Buddhist
> literature. In accordance with the old sramana tradition, describing
> the mind as Samsara [[[cittam eva samsara]]), the mind is said to
> arise due to one's ignorance about samskaras and has to be stopped by
> the practitioner.
>
> (註21) Thus the translation of samskara as samsara in early Chinese
> Buddhist literature brings to light the accumulative function of
> samskaras as forces or factors creating the universe in terms of
> proliferation of mind. This rendering is intended to include all five
> aggregates of existence and is also often used in this sense(註22).
>
> It is not surprising that a question crops out in this connection in
> the Mahavibhasa [T.27, 384c] ; why the samskara is not called the
> aggregate of self [我蘊] , which is answered by saying, because the
> pudgala is not the real characteristic of all samskaras.